# How should I calculate the redshift of an object if I know its light travel distance?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, distance, redshift

If an object placed at hubble horizon i.e. 14.4 billion light years approx sends a light ray today and it reaches on earth sometimes in the future so how can I calculate its redshift when it will reach the earth as the light ray will travel more distance than 14.4 billion light years.

Similarly can I calculate red shift of the object which is placed farther than cosmic event horizon (theoritically).

Apart from these

If possible, please share formula for following too.
a) I have current distance of an object, I want to calculate past distance of an object for given time (5 billion years ago, 7 billion years ago etc).

b) I have light travel distance of an object, I want to calculate the distance when light was emitted.

c) I have current distance of an object, I have to calculate the time to reach the light to us if it is emitted today.

Comment: I am guessing that the reason you have not received answers is that you have not shown any effort to calculate anything yourself. Also, you have asked a lot of questions rather than a single question. I suggest that you should make an effort to answer one question of your choice yourself, Some of the math skills needed, like perhaps integration, you may not know. If that is the case, you might ask for help in finding a source for learning this.

Comment: @Buzz I think, the questions appear more like college assignment because I didn't write the formulae of a(t) and z using LaTex Equation editor.
BTW I tried to figure out the answer 1st and 2nd. I hope they should be correct but it is no assignment , I cannot verify the answers.
a. I found the way to calculate scale factor on certain time,using the a(t) I could calculate the distance of the object any given time.
b. I found to calculate the Initial Distance by Proper Distance.

But these are past based calculations and last question depends on future based calculations so still in queue.